# is there a way to convert image into grid of controls in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, crossword

i want to create a simple crosswords game in android studio ,so i created image with the characters

for the words , my issue is how to  converte this image into control UI ?

vector  images  , dynamic control creation

Comment: What have you tried so far?